# Is an object file a list by default?

Tags: python

I've encountered two versions of code that both can accomplish the same task with a little difference in the code itself:

```
with open("file") as f:
   for line in f:
     print line
```

and

```
with open("file") as f:
   data = f.readlines() 
   for line in data:
     print line
```

My question is, is the file object `f` a list by default just like `data`? If not, why does the first chunk of code work? Which version is the better practice?

Comment: the more Pythonic approach is to iterate over the file directly - as your first example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In both cases, you are getting a file line-by-line. The method is different.

With your first version:

```
with open("file") as f:
   for line in f:
     print line
```

While you are interating over the file line by line, the file contents are not resident fully in memory (unless it is a 1 line file).

The [open](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) built-in function returns a [file object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#bltin-file-objects) -- not a list. That object supports iteration; in this case returning individual strings that are each group of characters in the file terminated by either a carriage return or the end of file.

You can write a loop that is similar to what `for line in f: print line` is doing under the hood:

```
with open('file') as f:
    while True:
        try:
            line=f.next()
        except StopIteration:
            break
        else:
            print line
```

With the second version:

```
with open("file") as f:
   data = f.readlines()    # equivelent to data=list(f)
   for line in data:
     print line
```

You are using a method of a file object ([file.readlines()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.readlines)) that reads the entire file contents into memory as a list of the individual lines. The code is then iterating over that list.

You can write a similar version of that as well that highlights the iterators under the hood:

```
with open('file') as f:
    data=list(f)
    it=iter(data)
    while True:
        try:
            line=it.next()
        except StopIteration:
            break
        else:
            print line
```

In both of your examples, you are using a [for loop](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) to loop over items in a sequence. The items are the same in each case (individual lines of the file) but the underlying sequence is different. In the first version, the sequence is a file object; in the second version it is a list. Use the first version if you just want to deal with each line. Use the second if you want a list of lines.

Read Ned Batchelder's excellent [overview on looping and iteration](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/iter.html) for more.

Answer (score 11):

`File` object is not a `list` - it's an object that conforms to *iterator* interface ([docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types)). I.e. it implements `__iter__` method that returns an *iterator* object. That *iterator* object implements both `__iter__` and `next` methods allowing iteration over the collection.

It happens that the `File` object is it's own iterator ([docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.next)) meaning `file.__iter__()` returns `self`.

Both `for line in file` and `lines = file.readlines()` are equivalent in that they yield the same result if used to get/iterator over **all** lines in the file. **But**, `file.next()` **buffers** the contents from the file (it reads *ahead*) to speed up the process of reading, effectively moving the file descriptor to position **exact to or farther** than where the last line ended. This means that if you have used `for line in file`, read some lines and the stopped the iteration (you haven't reach end of the file) and now called `file.readlines()`, the first line returned **might not** be the full line following the last line iterated over the `for` loop.

When you use `for x in my_it`, the interpreter calls `my_it.__iter__()`. Now, the `next()` method is being called on the object returned by the previous call, and for each call it's return value is being assigned to `x`. When `next()` raises `StopIteration`, the loop ends.

**Note**: A valid iterator implementation should ensure that once `StopIteration` is raised, it should remain to be risen for all subsequent calls to `next()`.

Comment: "usually returns `self`" - this is generally a bad way to implement iterators actually. The iterator object needs to hold some state saying what the next element is. If it was the same as the iterable object, that means two iterators on the same underlying sequence would work buggily. It makes sense for a `file` because you can't randomly access any line in it, and because a `file` already internally retains state about how far you've read into it, but not for other collections.

Comment: If you would like random access to collection's items I'd rather suggest using `__getitem__` instead of an iterator. I agree that returning `self` is not the best way to write iterators - you'd have to ensure the iterator to be valid for subsequent loops, etc. It all depends on your use case - if the underlying collection is a one-time read only then it looks fine.

Comment: "the underlying collection is a one-time read only" - that's actually my point. Almost no collections are. You also missed my point with "random access". What I was saying is that **if** a collection *supports* random access to its elements, **then** its iterator should never be `self`. Precisely for the reasons you've just mentioned. And obviously you might want to iterate even over collections that *support* random access. I was talking about the nature of the underlying collection, not about how it's being *used*.

Comment: You might want to add that what `file.next()` will do is read a new line from the underlying file and return it to make it clearer why it's equivalent to `readlines()`.

Comment: @millimoose, added the `next()` usage in context of `readlines()`. It might yield unexpected results when using `readlines()` on file on which iteration was ended prematurely.

Answer (score 4):

`f` is a filehandle, not a list.  It is [iterable](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-iterable).

Answer (score 0):

A file is an *iterable*. Lots of objects, including lists are *iterable*, which just means that they can be used in a for loop to sequentially yield an object to bind the for iterator variable to.

Both versions of your code accomplish iteration line by line. The second versions reads the whole file into memory and constructs a list; the first may not read the whole file first. The reason why you might prefer the second is that you want to close the file before something else modifies it; the first might be preferred if the file is very large.